# sed making digit optional

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to replace a date in the format 08/09/2014 but at the same time also the format 8/9/14 using `sed`. I know the + sign is supposed to match one or more occurrences, and ? 0 or more. I've tried both but none of the dates are being replaced with "testing". I was expecting this would find 1 or more digits followed by a slash, 1 or more digits followed by a slash, 4 digits.

Do I need to escape the special character, or what is wrong here?

```
sed -f mySed.sed dates.csv

# mySed.sed file
s#[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]#testing#g

# sample line in dates.csv
...,20/01/2001,2/1/2009,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` quantifiers in your regular expression, and you can use a range for the last set.

```
s#[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+/[0-9]\{2,4\}#testing#g
```

Or you can use the range quantifier throughout your pattern.

```
s#[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{2,4\}#testing#g
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made several mistakes. Here is a working example:

```
echo '20/01/2001,2/1/2009' | sed 's~[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\{1,2\}~toto~g'
```

Note that the `?` means "optional" (in other words 0 or 1 time) and must be escaped.

To be more precise, I have choosen to use this quantifier `{m,n}` instead of `+`. But if you use `+` don't forget to escape it `\+` otherwise it will be seen as a literal character.

Comment: `+` and `?` are not posix compliant but usefull with GNU sed and more "regex" minded. {m,n} (escaped) is univoque on every sed version.

Comment: @M42: Thanks. It's time to prepare my favorite meal.